# Change views via code using xcode 4.2 and storyboard?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

How would I go about changing views via code using xcode 4.2 and storyboard?
I'm trying to change views once a dynamic table view cell is clicked.
Since its dynamic I can't just link it with a segue...

I've tried changing using this code as suggested by another article on Stack Overflow but it doesn't work:

```
 UIViewController *alertView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"alertView"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:alertView animated:YES];
```

Here's a snippet of my code, hope it helps!

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
if(indexPath.row==0){
     UIViewController *alertView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"alertView"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:alertView animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"This code is being called...");
}
```

Comment: "Since its dynamic I can't just link it with a segue..." er, yes you can - just ctrl-drag from the prototype to the next view controller. Have you tried this and had no luck?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your storyboard create a segue from your `UITableViewController` to your `alertView`. Make sure you do it by control dragging from the Controller (next to the First Responder icon) to your `alertView` rather than dragging from your table cell or something like that. Choose a segue type of 'Push'. Click on the segue's properties and make sure to give it an identifier like `AlertViewSegue`

Now you can programmatically invoke your segue with code like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(indexPath.row==0){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"AlertViewSegue" sender:self];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is one of the better storyboard tutorials and it happens to use tableviews.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Comment: In case I was unclear, I want to know how to switch views when a user clicks on a dynamic table view cell. I already know how to make a dynamic table view using an array. I skimmed over the tutorial and downloaded the source code and that still didn't clear anything up as nothing happens when you click on there dynamic cells.